# Can't read the value from pipe correctly

Tags: c, cygwin, pipe, fork

I am trying to initiate a simple pipe in `C` (using CygWin and Dev-C++) to pass values between a parent and a single child. Here is the `parent` code (pipesnd.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int FIFO[2];
    char *msg = "This is a test message";
    char str[10];



    if (pipe(FIFO) == -1)
    {
        printf("cannot create pipe\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    write(FIFO[1], msg, strlen(msg));

    sprintf(str, "%d", FIFO[0]);
    printf("I am the parent and this was in the pipe: %s \n", str);
    fflush(stdout);




    switch (fork())
    {
    case 0:
        execl("c:/Dev-Cpp/Lift 2/pipercv", "pipercv", str, NULL);  
        exit(1);
    case -1:
        perror("fork() failed:");
        exit(2);
    default:

    }






    exit(0);
}
```

And the `child` code (pipercv.c):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#define NBUF 100
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd;
    char buf[NBUF];
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("expect pipercv fd\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fd = atoi(argv[1]);


    read(fd, buf, 20);
    buf[20] = '\0';
    printf("I am the child and this was in the pipe: %s \n", buf);
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(10);

}
```

Result:

[image]

How can I pass/see the entire message in both child and parent (bidirectional)?

Comment: the posted code does not compile.  It is missing `#include <unistd.h>`  the `switch` statement has a few problems in syntax that can be corrected by ending the `default:` case with `break;`

Comment: this line: `printf("expect pipercv fd\n");` should really be a USAGE statement, similar to: `printf( "USAGE: %s fileDescriptor\n", argv[0] );`

Comment: in the child, the returned value from the call to `read()` should be used as the offset into buf[] to insert the '\0'.

Comment: the parent should be calling `waitpid()` so the pipe stays open until the child has read the complete message from the pipe.

Comment: @user3629249 Can you please explain more?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you read 20 characters from the buf, then you add `\0` as 20th character and you end up with that output. Your message
`This is a test message`
contains more characters.

Comment: Then what about the `parent` process? Why does it show only the value of `3`? How can I ask `child` process to show the entire message regardless of its length whether it is 20 characters long, 30 or whatever?

Comment: *Why does it show only the value of 3*  because the '3' is the file descriptor number, not the number of characters written to the pipe

Comment: @user3629249 How can I fix that then?

Answer (score 0):

the transmitted string is actually 24 byte 'this is a test message' + the trailing NUL byte.

reading only 20 characters is the main part of the error.

Suggest in the child, to initialized the buffer to all NUL bytes:

```
char buf[NBUF] = {'\0'};
```

Then there is no need to insert a terminating NUL byte after the data is read.

To assure the correct number of bytes are read in the child, suggest a second command line parameter to the child that indicates the number of bytes to read.

Rather than using a select/read loop with a select timeout, Use the passed in byte count in the read() statement.

Comment: Well, I tried to add `char str[10], Length[];   sprintf(Length,"%d",strlen(msg));` to parent code and also changed the `execl` to `execl("c:/Dev-Cpp/Lift 2/pipercv", "pipercv" , Length , str, NULL); `. I also updated the child code accordingly to receive an extra argument for the length of the passed message i.e. `Length = atoi(argv[1]); fd = atoi(argv[2]); read(fd, buf, Length);` But the output is still blank. Can you please advise in more detail?